# Как прижать кнопку к низу блока?

Tags: html, css

Как прижать кнопку к низу блока, чтобы она всегда была внизу вне зависимости от наполнения блока контентом.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

не подходит, потому что блоки могут растягиваться по длине и кнопки выпадают из потока.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  color: steelblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.button {
  position: absoulte;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
  <p class="text">текст</p>
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
  <p class="text">Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста</p>
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt="" />
  <p class="text">текст</p>
  <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понял что значит, кнопки выпадают из потока, но если имеется ввиду чтобы при растягивании блока по ширине, они всегда оставались по центру, то попробуйте обернуть кнопку в контейнер `btn-cont` сделать его абсолютным и на всю ширину. Внутри расположите Вашу кнопку и сделайте контейнер `flex`, с `justify-content: center`. Тем самым блок всегда будет внизу и при расширении или уменьшении родителя кнопка будет располагаться в центре. Если же имеется ввиду, чтобы текст не заезжал на кнопку, то добавьте родителю `padding-bottom: (высота кнопки +- несколько пикселей)` Пример ниже (без отступов):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 320px;
  color: steelblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px
}

.text {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.btn-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/223/200/150" alt="">
  <p class="text">текст</p>
  <div class="btn-cont">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/150" alt="">
  <p class="text">Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста Очень много текста</p>
  <div class="btn-cont">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150" alt="" />
  <p class="text">текст</p>
  <div class="btn-cont">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в центральном блоке кнопка поверх текста, а она должна быть после текста прижата к низу блока

Comment: @Imp3l поправил ответ. Так?